# Optimization over 7 constants, running a function 10,000,000 times

Tags: performance, r

I am not quite sure how to attach my data, but it is 5737 observations of 3 variables. Variables `V` and `P` are strictly < 0, and variable `R` is -2 < `R` < 2.

The last function, `correcttot`, will help me find the optimal constants, or ranges of constants, for this function. However, the function that it runs over, `percentcorrect`, takes several seconds to run, which means that repeating it 10,000,000 times is not feasible.

[Data](http://we.tl/J0qBfgnPUY)

```
setwd("~/Desktop")
dat<-read.csv(file="data.csv",sep=",",header=T)
attach(dat)
###################################################################################
voltoalph<-function(v,c){  # Where V is a data vector and C is a constant
  alpha<-c(rep(0,length(v)))
  for(i in 1:length(v)){
    alpha[i+1]<-abs(c*(v[i]/max(v,na.rm=TRUE)))
  }
  alpha
}
voltoenen<-function(v,c){  # Where V is a data vector and C is a constant
  enen<-c(rep(1,length(v)))
  for(i in 1:length(v)){
    enen[i+1]<-abs((v[i]/max(v,na.rm=TRUE)))
  }
  enhelp<-1/(enen)
  enhelp2<-c*(enhelp/max(enhelp))
  enhelp2
}

ema<-function(v,n,a){     # Where V is a data vector and n is a contant and a is a constant
  avevec<-c(rep(0,n)) 
  for(i in 1:n){  
    avevec[i]<-((1-a[i])^(n-i))*v[i]}
  divvec<-c(rep(0,n))  
  for(i in 1:n){ 
    divvec[i]<-((1-a[i])^(n-i)) 
  }
  sum(avevec)/sum(divvec) 
}
betaema<-function(v,n,a,l){ # Where V is a data vector and n,a,l are constants
  secondvec<-c(rep(0, length(v)))
  for(i in l:length(v)){
    secondvec[i]<-ema(v[(i-n[i]+1):i],n[i],a)
  }
  secondvec
}
#################################################################################################################
howright<-function(v,r,c,l){   # Where v and r are data vectors and c,l are constants
  rightvec<-0
  for(i in l:(length(r)-c)){
    if((v[i]*mean(r[i+1]:r[i+c]))>0){
      rightvec<-rightvec+1
    }
    else{
      rightvec<-rightvec
    }
  }
  rightvec/(length(r)-l-c)
}
#################################################################################################################
percentcorrect<-function(ca1,ca2,cn1,cn2,e,d,c,v,p,r){   ###V, P, and R are data vectors, rest constant
  vol1<-voltoalph(v,ca1)
  vol2<-voltoalph(v,ca2)
  ens1<-voltoenen(v,cn1)
  ens2<-voltoenen(v,cn2)
  als<-c(vol1)
  als2<-c(vol2)
  n1<-c(ens1)
  n2<-c(ens2)
  anotherema1<-betaema(p,n1,als,max(cn1,cn2))
  anotherema2<-betaema(p,n2,als2,max(cn1,cn2))
  slope1<-c(rep(0,length(p)))
  slope2<-c(rep(0,length(p)))
  for(i in (max(cn1,cn2)+d):length(anotherema1)){
    slope1[i]<-(anotherema1[i]-anotherema1[i-d])/d
  }
  for(i in (max(cn1,cn2)+e):length(anotherema2)){
    slope2[i]<-(anotherema2[i]-anotherema2[i-e])/e
  }
  sig<-slope1-slope2
  hvec<-howright(sig,r,c,max(cn1,cn2))
  hvec
}
##########################################################################################
correcttot<-function(v,p,r){    ###Where v, p, and r are data vectors
  correct3<-array(0,dim=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10))
  for(i in 1:10){
    for(j in 1:10){
      for(k in 1:10){
        for(l in 1:10){
          for(m in 2:10){
            for(n in 2:10){
              for(o in 1:10){
                correct3[i,j,k,l,m,n,o]<-percentcorrect((i/10),(j/10),(20*k),(20*l),m,n,o,v,p,r)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  print(correct3)
}
newvec<-correcttot(vl,p,rt)  # run it on the vectors vl, p and rt
which(newvec==max(newvec2),arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: Post some data too. Say 10-20 lines at random. Or if you can link to it over dropbox.

Comment: Added the first 20-something lines of the data. Let me know if it is better to link the whole file. Thank you again Mike!

Comment: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/523562/newdata.csv       Here is a link to the full dataset

Answer (score 4):

You have several loops that are completely unnecessary. Remove them and you will see dramatic speedups. Take `voltoalph` and `voltoenen` for example:

```
voltoalph2 <- function(v,c) {
  # v: a data vector
  # c: a scalar constant
  c(0, c[1L] * (v / max(v, na.rm=TRUE)))
}
voltoenen2 <- function(v,c) {
  # v: a data vector
  # c: a scalar constant
  enhelp <- 1 / c(1, abs(v / max(v, na.rm=TRUE)))
  c[1L] * (enhelp / max(enhelp))
}
require(microbenchmark)
v <- 1:10000
microbenchmark(voltoalph(v, 2), voltoalph2(v, 2))
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr        min          lq        mean     median          uq        max neval cld
#   voltoalph(v, 2) 105004.652 106038.7245 108767.0230 106725.827 108326.7975 151482.035   100   b
#  voltoalph2(v, 2)     81.925     83.5825    141.3382     89.794     91.6065   5350.052   100  a 
identical(voltoalph(v, 2), voltoalph2(v, 2))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(voltoenen(v, 2), voltoenen2(v, 2))
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr        min         lq        mean     median        uq        max neval cld
#   voltoenen(v, 2) 103595.526 105433.803 108797.6308 106882.274 110160.65 148550.397   100   b
#  voltoenen2(v, 2)    200.275    203.182    227.6582    207.932    220.57   1007.375   100  a 
identical(voltoenen(v, 2), voltoenen2(v, 2))
# [1] TRUE
```

The vectorized (non-loop) versions are over 1000, and 500 times faster (for `voltoalph` and `voltoenen`, respectively), and provide identical output. `percentcorrect` calls each of those functions two times, which makes the speed improvement have twice the impact.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: Thats really helpful. Can that same paradigm be used for a function where the references are non constant? Say for betaema where n and a change?

Comment: Or more importantly for ema, because I imagine the 2 loops in that set the time back.

Comment: @user3678028: `ema` can be vectorized. I don't think `betaema` can without a significant tradeoff in the amount of memory used. That said, it would be very simple to code in C/C++.